# How to get outer html text from gecko web browser?

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I need to make a web browser in C# using Gecko Xulrunner.
Now, I need to get outer HTML from gecko web browser. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create and initialize the browser, you can access the document property and its body in a following way:

```
var htmlString = this.YourGeckoBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

Regards